# Firebase cloud function with Google searchanalytics API / SDK: 'GaxiosError: Request contains an invalid argument.'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-search-console

Im trying to reach the google searchanalytics API through my firebase cloud function to retrieve some of the logged in user's search console data. im using the googleapis SDK like so:

import:

```
import {google} from "googleapis";
```

cloud function:

```
  const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret
  );

  auth.setCredentials({refresh_token: refreshToken});

  const accessToken = await auth.refreshAccessToken();

  auth.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken.credentials.access_token});

  const searchconsole = google.searchconsole({version: "v1", auth});

  try {
    const res = await searchconsole.searchanalytics.query({
      siteUrl: "domain:domainname.com", // Replace with the user's site URL
      requestBody: {
        startDate: "2023-01-01", // Define the date range for the data
        endDate: "2023-01-31",
      },
    });

    return res.data; // Contains the CTR and other search analytics data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error querying Search Console:", err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Failed to query Search Console", err);
  }
```

this is resulting into the error:

```
Error querying Search Console: GaxiosError: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

I've tried the accesstoken / refreshtoken in postman and those work so it's not about the actual auth itself. I'm well aware that the token flow is not correct here but this is to test retreiving the data first.

I've checked a example from google itself here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/webmasters/query.js and the parameters for the query here seem identical (quite simple too). Yet the error indicates something is wrong there?

Could really use some help! Thanks